# NServiceBus Could not find a concrete type mapped to XXX error

Tags: nservicebus

I am trying to publish an event which is defined as an interface:

```
Bus.Publish<IAccountCreated>(m => { m.Key = Guid.NewGuid(); });
```

When using the JSON serializer, it gives me the error:

> Could not find a concrete type mapped to Contracts.IAccountCreated

It works fine with the XML serializer.

My endpoint configuration:

```
Configure.With()
    .DefaultBuilder()
    .JsonSerializer() <-- when this is here I get the error.
    .DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("Website"))
    .DefiningEventsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.Contains("Contracts"))
```

I'm using NServiceBus 3.3.3.

Comment: move your conventions just right after the With() and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, that worked. Will this be "fixed" at some point? Aren't fluent interfaces supposed to be order agnostic? Thanks

Comment: Yes we're definitely going to fix it. It won't make it into 4.0 though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the order you do things in the fluent interface is important.

This works:

```
Configure.With()
    .DefaultBuilder()
    .DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("Website"))
    .DefiningEventsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.Contains("Contracts"))
    .JsonSerializer() <-- moving this down works
```